# Allow output of run code snippet to be resized by the user

Tags: feature-request

Some questions on stackoverflow based on css where we have to check responsive of layout for different width.

Currently what we have to do:

1. Click on full page
2. Open Inspect element to resize width

It will be helpful in term of user experience if we can resize width within output window.
[image]